# Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY

Tags: ubuntu, email, ssl-certificate, certificate

I've created a mail server with https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver. Everything works, except the certificate.
I have tested the TLS on [CheckTLS.com](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver) and I've got the following output messages:

[image]

As you can see on the image, it says, that `Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY (dataxu.io != email.dataxu.io | DNS:email.dataxu.io)`, do I miss any DNS entry?

The DNS records are setting up as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, but you aren't able to interpret it correctly:

> Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY (dataxu.io != email.dataxu.io |
>   DNS:email.dataxu.io)

Here:

- `dataxu.io` is the hostname on the certificate
- `!=` it's not equal to...
- `email.dataxu.io`, your SMTP banner (on `220-email.dataxu.io` message)
- `DNS:email.dataxu.io` is the DNS name from your `MX 10 email.dataxu.io.`

You need to either replace the certificate with a certificate for `email.dataxu.io` or change your SMTP banner (& DNS `MX` hostname) to `dataxu.io`.