# Error Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY - Test certificates TLS Exchange 2016 cu21

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, lets-encrypt, exchange-2016

Practicing with the certificates, in let's encrypt [win-acme](https://www.win-acme.com/) normal is created, I send and receive normal mail, https in owa and the other services

Testing with [checktls](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver), it gives me an alert message :

Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY:

```
(mail.contoso.com != mail | DNS:mail | DNS:mail.lan.contoso.com)
```

I don't understand the mail.lan.contoso.com DNS error.
I thought the error was the DNS SPLIT, but reading in the [forum](https://serverfault.com/questions/1009937/cert-hostname-does-not-verify) they comment on something about the error.

I understand that the other connectors should not be changed in forums, books and tutorials, nobody changes them. That is why a new connector is created to receive from the internet, to which the FQDN can be changed.

Recommendations of this [forum](https://www.alitajran.com/configure-internal-dns-exchange-2016/), my dns settings :

### Private AD DNS (lan.contoso.com)

| Record Type | DNS Name | Internal IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | mail.lan.contoso.com | 192.168.1.4 |
| A | DC01.lan.contoso.com | 192.168.1.3 |

### Private DNS (contoso.com) SPLIT

| Record Type | DNS Name | Internal IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | mail.contoso.com | 192.168.1.4 |
| A | autodiscover.contoso.com | 192.168.1.4 |

### Public DNS (contoso.com)

| Record Type | DNS Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | mail.contoso.com | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| A | autodiscover.contoso.com | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx |
| MX | @ | mail.contoso.com |

Comment: Here is a similar thread, please check if the answers in it are helpful: **Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY, certificate let's encrypt exchange 2016 cu 21** (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/536588/cert-hostname-does-not-verify-certificate-let39s-e.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much testing, I understand some of the error message in [CheckTls](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver). It is the certificate used by the Exchange reception connector.
I retest in [CheckTls](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver) and passed the entire test without errors.

Thanks for the advice `@Lutz Willek` , I will continue to practice.

---

I share my solution with you, I hope it helps others with this problem.

I do not know if it is a good procedure, the solution that I am using
Use the following [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/clients/pop3-and-imap4/configure-authenticated-smtp?view=exchserver-2019) for reference.

1. Verify the Let's Encrypt certificate is created and services enabled

```
    Get-ExchangeCertificate | Format-List FriendlyName,Thumbprint,Issuer,Subject,CertificateDomains,Services
```

2. Identify the reception connector to assign, I was more focused on
   anonymous users

```
    Get-ReceiveConnector | where {$_.Bindings -like '*25' -AND $_.PermissionGroups -like '*AnonymousUsers*'} | Format-List Identity,Bindings,RemoteIPRanges,PermissionGroups
```

3. Having identified the connector, I proceed to assign the certificate

```
    $cert = Get-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint xxxxxxxx
```

```
    $tlscertificatename = "<i>$($cert.Issuer)<s>$($cert.Subject)"
```

```
    Set-ReceiveConnector "Server_Name\Default Frontend Server_Name" -TlsCertificateName $tlscertificatename
```

4. Verify if the certificate was assigned to the reception connector

```
    Get-ReceiveConnector -Identity "Server_Name\Default Frontend Server_Name" | Format-List Name,Fqdn,TlsCertificateName
```

Comment: I'm glad that you've fixed the TLS issue, thanks for your sharing at the same time. If everything works well, you could mark your solution as the best answer so that others with the same problem will find it.

Answer (score 1):

The other [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1009937/cert-hostname-does-not-verify) is 100% correct.

What happened is that a (internal) server has been created, using the host name `mail.lan.contoso.com`. The error is that the certificate which has created for this host is still presented in case the dns name `mail.contoso.com` is used to connect to the server.

---

So you **need** to do the following, in order to create a functional service:

- Remove the split DNS configuration for `autodiscover.contoso.com`, as a specific name resolution to `192.168.1.4` is not needed within your internal network. (As the public name resolution can be always used)
- Configure your clients to connect to `mail.contoso.com`. (check the autodiscover settings)
- Configure your exchange server to use the certificate which has been created for `mail.contoso.com` - currently, the certificate for `mail.lan.contoso.com` is presented.

---

What you **could** do, to increase reliability and decrease maintenance effort: (This allows to split the service from the server)

- On server side, configure a second IP internal IP address `192.168.1.5` and point the internal name resolution to for `mail.contoso.com` to this IP address. (Do not change `mail.lan.contoso.com` which still points to the server itself)
- On server (exchange) side, configure the mail services to listen on this specific IP `192.168.1.5` instead `192.168.1.4`.

---

What you could at least **consider**, is not using [split DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) at all:

- My experience indicates that there are considerable disadvantages if split DNS is not implemented thoroughly, and also that the average administrator's network experience is unfortunately not sufficient to oversee and to deal with all the associated challenges.
- Another important reason is a simplified network design, which helps (among other advantages) to isolate a root cause faster in case of an incident.
- There are not many real advantages of a split DNS setup that cannot be achieved more efficiently using other methods.